# Spring data neo4j 3.0.0 - labels support

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

Is it somehow possible to use label feature of neo4j 2.0 using `spring-data-neo4j`? I know that `2.X` versions of `spring-data-neo4j` did not support labels. I am wondering if it is possible to somehow annotate domain object and give him some label in `3.0.0` version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know from Michael Hunger they might introduce dynamic label support in SDN 3.0.1.
They have a `@Labels` annotation but it is not yet used.

Labels are used for the new schema based index but they are not dynamic. You can't specify or change them. Because of this I am using Neo4j directly.

Check this [issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAGRAPH-436) for future information.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the annotation in code and I was wondering if it is a placeholder for now or is it usable.

Comment: I also saw the annotation in code and I started using it based on an example on how it might be used (`@Labels private Set<String> labels`). I thought it was already implemented :)

Comment: That ticket mentioned fixed since 3.0.1.